# VM import to EC2 with EFI partition

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ami, ec2-ami

I'm trying to import Hyper-V image to AWS EC2 using aws ec2 import-image command and faced with issue.

[image]

Googling this I found that EC2 Import supporting VHDX but not supporting UEFI.

I'm not very familiar with this partitions types. Maybe I could somehow convert this partition to which that supported by EC2? If yes, could you please guide me?

I'm need to do same for Windows Server and CentOS.

thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two types of partition tables on Intel based systems (I am excluding Macs).

The first type is MBR - this is the format that EC2 supports. This format goes back to the original PC days.

The second type is UEFI - this is a new format that supports disk drives larger that 2 TB (MBR can with 4096 byte sectors but that is another story).

EC2 does not support EFI partitioned disk drives nor does it support UEFI boot loaders. There is no easy method of switching a system from UEFI to MBR. This requires moving the data on the disk around, reconfiguring boot loaders, etc. There might be a third party tool to do this, but make sure that you have a backup first.

Comment: AWS/EC2 does support GPT partition tables, but only with legacy boot, ie a 2MB partition (type EF02 - BIOS boot) into which to install a classic BIOS bootloader like grub.

Comment: @gdamjan - GPT is only a small part of UEFI. UEFI includes boot loaders, tools, security, diagnostics, etc.